# Problem Proof of matrix Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let 2 $v \times 1$ column matrices X and Y such that the $v \times v$ matrix $A = I +XY^{T}$ to be invertible.Show that $A^{-1}= I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}$

My effort:

I have to show that $AA^{-1}=I$. So:

$$AA^{-1}=(I +XY^{T})\left(I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}\right)$$

\begin{align*}
AA^{-1}&=(I +XY^{T})\left(I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}\right)\\
&= I\left(I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}\right) + XY^{T}\left(I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}\right)\\
&= I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T} + XY^{T} - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}XY^{T}\\
\end{align*}

How I proceed further ?

Comment: Note that $Y^{\top}X$ is a scalar in the last expression. So $XY^{\top}XY^{\top} = (Y^{\top}X) (XY^{\top})$. Now combine the last term with the second to see if you can simplify to obtain the final expression.

Comment: @sudeep5221 how? $\frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}X(Y^{T}X)Y^{T}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $Y^T$ is a $1\times n$ row vector, and $X$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector. Therefore, $Y^TX=b$, where $b$ is a scalar (a number).

\begin{align*}
AA^{-1}&=(I +XY^{T})\left(I - \frac{1}{1+Y^{T}X}XY^{T}\right)\\
\\
&=(I +XY^{T})\left(I - \frac{1}{1+b}XY^{T}\right)\\
\\
&= I+XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}XY^TXY^T\\
\\
&= I+XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}X(Y^TX)Y^T\\
\\
&= I+XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}X(b)Y^T\\
\\
&= I+XY^T-\frac{1}{1+b}XY^T-\frac{b}{1+b}XY^T\\
\\
&= I+\left(1-\frac{1}{1+b}-\frac{b}{1+b}\right)XY^T\\
\\
&= I+\left(0\right)XY^T\\
\\
&=I
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If you can explain please the last line.This is the only part that I don't get.

Comment: Sure, I add more steps, is this clear now?

Comment: yes thanks a lot. I appreciate it.